# How would I solve for the value of this odd integral between 0 and (10pi)/3

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to get the value of this one integral,

$$2\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{10\pi}{3}} x \sqrt{-cos^2(x-\frac{10\pi}{3}) + cos(x-\frac{10\pi}{3}) + \frac{3}{4}} dx$$

between $0$ and $\frac{10\pi}{3}$, and I can't/don't want to solve this and no program I find is able to solve it either. How would I solve this integral, and what is the solution? I'm trying to find the surface area of the solid of revolution formed by $-sin(x - \frac{10\pi}{3}) - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{5\pi}{3}$ rotated around the y axis.

Is there any way I could get help with this? Thank you!

Not sure about the existence of a typical antiderivative for this, but I'm thinking it doesn't exist. What would be a good way to approximate this in the absence of one, and how?

Comment: The integrand is not even defined on certain subintervals of $[0, 10\pi /3]$. I suggest you first look into the graph of the integrand.

Comment: The integral seems not to be appropriate for the considered surface. The expression is mistaken.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go and look over it again.